# Combine output in single line using echo in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, echo

I want to modify the below script to give me out put like

```
Number of processes on machine1 are 1

Number of processes on machine2 are 3

Number of processes on machine3 are 7

Number of processes on machine4 are 2
```

Please can someone help?

===============================

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

pushd "%~dp0"

echo %date% %time% 

TASKLIST /S machine1 | grep -c "process" 
TASKLIST /S machine2 | grep -c "process" 
TASKLIST /S machine3 | grep -c "process" 
TASKLIST /S machine4 | grep -c "process"
```

================================

Comment: Do you have grep under windows?

Comment: Please edit your code for readability. E.g. indent any code by four spaces. Then, it is highlighted in gray.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter if IMAGENAME command to give you just the necessary processes.
I used a for command because output of IMAGENAME behaves strange...it is always displayed at the beginning of the line.

```
@echo off 
set compName1=machine1
for /f %%a in ('tasklist /NH /FO CSV /FI "IMAGENAME eq process" ^| find /C /V ""') do (
    echo Number of processes on %compName1% are %%a
)
```